# How can I marginalize $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ out of my hierarchical model?

Tags: hierarchical-bayesian, marginal-distribution

Suppose I have the following hierarchical distribution:

$$\mathbf{y} \sim \text{Normal}(\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta} + \mathbf{K}\boldsymbol{\alpha}, \sigma^2\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_y),$$
$$\boldsymbol{\alpha} \sim \text{Normal}(\boldsymbol{0}, \sigma^2_\alpha\mathbf{I}),$$
$$\boldsymbol{\beta} \sim \text{Normal}(\boldsymbol{\mu}_\beta, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_\beta),$$
$$\sigma^2_\alpha \sim \text{IG}(\alpha_\alpha, \beta_\alpha),$$
$$\sigma^2 \sim \text{IG}(\alpha_\sigma, \beta_\sigma),$$
where $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_y$ is a diagonal matrix, $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{K}$ are known, and $\boldsymbol{\mu}_\beta$, $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_\beta$, $\alpha_\alpha$, $\beta_\alpha$, $\alpha_\sigma$, and $\beta_\sigma$ are fixed hyperparameters. Further, suppose that $\mathbf{K}$ acts as a mapping matrix, where it selects two values in $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ for each response $y_i$ (i.e., $y_i$ may have mean $\mathbf{X}_i^T\boldsymbol{\beta} + \alpha_3 + \alpha_8$).

I would like to marginalize over $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$. Is the resulting hierarchical model simply
$$\mathbf{y} \sim \text{Normal}(\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}, 2\sigma^2_\alpha\mathbf{I} + \sigma^2\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_y),$$
$$\boldsymbol{\beta} \sim \text{Normal}(\boldsymbol{\mu}_\beta, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_\beta),$$
$$\sigma^2_\alpha \sim \text{IG}(\alpha_\alpha, \beta_\alpha),$$
$$\sigma^2 \sim \text{IG}(\alpha_\sigma, \beta_\sigma)?$$

This seems a bit too trivial, so I'm wondering if I messed up somewhere. My thinking is that, regardless of which response we have, there will be an addition of two normally distributed random variables with variance $\sigma^2_\alpha$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution does not account for the fact that responses $y_i$ and $y_j$ will be positively correlated if they depend on the same value $\alpha_k$.

The correct variance for $\boldsymbol{y}$ in the marginalised model is $\sigma^2_\alpha\mathbf{K}\mathbf{K}^T + \sigma^2\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_y$.

As the design matrix $\mathbf{K}$ always picks out two values from $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$, the diagonal terms in $\mathbf{K}\mathbf{K}^T$ are all equal to 2.

Comment: So, is it ok to write $2\sigma^2_\alpha\mathbf{I} = \sigma^2_\alpha\mathbf{K}\mathbf{K}^T$, or is that not always the case?

Comment: Not always, no. It would only be the case if no element of $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ appears in more than one value of the response variable.

Comment: Try writing out $\mathbf{K}$ and evaluating $\mathbf{K} \mathbf{K}^T$ in the case where you have only two observations: $y_1$ with mean $\mathbf{X}_1^T\boldsymbol{\beta} + \alpha_1+ \alpha_2$, and $y_2$ with mean $\mathbf{X}_2^T\boldsymbol{\beta} + \alpha_2+ \alpha_3$.

Comment: I am beginning to see why this is the case. To obtain my (wrong) answer, I was using the addition of (not!) independent random variables. What is the math that you execute to get the correct specification? I see why it's right, but I'd like to understand how I could derive that myself.

Comment: I sent that message too early. I just used iterated expectation and variance properties because it's normal. I was thinking we'd need to do some cheeky integration technique, but that's not necessary here. Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: No problem at all.